# Named pipe messages corrupted (Win32,C)

Tags: c, winapi, named-pipes

I have some pipe communication code - received bytes are no match for sent bytes.
There is a loop where 'CallNamedPipe' is called to send messages to server.
Now only 1st message is received intact, all the rest are received partially filled with 0xCD byte.
It seems, that when I free the memory after sending - it is still being read by server thread.
MSDN says that CallNamedPipe() is a complete message sequence: open pipe, sent bytes and close the pipe.
So, this seems strange to me. I must mention, that this code is built by VC++ 6.0 - a very old compiler. Code runs on Windows 7, maybe I need to use compatibility mode? Both client and server executables run on the same physical system, not remotely. Client uses CreateProcess() on startup to start the server. The messages are sent much later on, so racing conditions should not matter, I hope.

Thanks for any advice.

```
============ Client side (pseudocode): ============
for (iPiece=0; iPiece < nPieces; ++iPiece)
{
    buffer = malloc (2048);

    // copy some data bytes into buffer (1..2048 bytes)
    // log 1st 32 DWORDS from message about to be sent

    if (! CallNamedPipe (name, buffer, nBytes, ..., 1000))
    {
        // diagnostics: call to GetLastError(), etc.
    }
    free (buffer);
}

============ Server side (pseudocode): ============
DWORD __stdcall ServerThreadProc (PVOID p)
{
    UINT    cbMaxMsg = 0x10000; // 64K for a pipe message
    PVOID   buffer = malloc (cbMaxMsg);
    HANDLE  hPipe;
    BOOL    fAbort = 0;

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe (name, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_WAIT | PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, cbMaxMsg, cbMaxMsg, 1000, NULL);

    while (fAbort == 0) // one of pipe messages sets fAbort=1, so thread can return.
    {
        if (ConnectNamedPipe (hPipe, NULL))
        {
            DWORD   bytesLoaded = 0;

            ReadFile (hPipe, buffer, cbMaxMsg, &bytesLoaded, NULL);
            if (bytesLoaded)
            {
                // log 1st 32 DWORDS from received message
                // process the pipe message (switch/case)
                // data may be written back to client after processing

                FlushFileBuffers (hPipe);
            }
            DisconnectNamedPipe (hPipe);
        }
        else
        {
            // diagnostics, GLE(), etc.
        }
    }

    free (buffer);
    CloseHandle (hPipe);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that is actually filling the buffers for sending, and processing the bytes that are read. On the client side, you are allocating a new buffer each time, but are you checking for allocation errors? Is `nBytes` the same value every time? On the server side, you are re-using a single buffer for every read of every client connection. Packets of different sizes are not going to use all of the same bytes in the buffer. if `ReadFile()` is successful, you have to take the value of `bytesLoaded` into account when processing the buffer. Are you doing that?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error in action.

Comment: 1) it is not a good idea to flush the read end of a pipe.  That will destroy bytes that you actually want to keep.   2) only connect to the pipe once and only disconnect once. 3)   a pipe has no idea about a 'record' it is just a stream of bytes.  Therefore, each read of the pipe could get 0 bytes or 1000 bytes or any other number of bytes.  This means a read of the pipe may contain any combination of data.  The code needs to implement some kind of protocol, so the code can determine when a 'write' from the client starts/ends (cont)

Comment: (cont)  Suggest a flag and count be the first part of each buffer sent from the client, Suggest the client only send the number of bytes that actually contain data, not the whole malloc'd buffer.  If none of the data will contain -1, that that could be the flag,  The server needs to be implemented as: read int size, if result==flag, then read count, then loop, calling read of count... count-previously read, etc.  accumulating the bytes into a buffer until whole record read.  Then process that record. then read, looking flag again.

Comment: MSDN for `CallNamedPipe()` says also that `If the message written to the pipe by the server process is longer than nOutBufferSize, CallNamedPipe returns FALSE, and GetLastError returns ERROR_MORE_DATA. The remainder of the message is discarded, because CallNamedPipe closes the handle to the pipe before returning.`. Are you sure that the message doesn't exceed the buffer? Do you check error for `ERROR_MORE_DATA`.? This even if you don't write any message from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Using `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` makes the pipe a message pipe.  It will give a message like behavior to the server.  If you try and read more than the standard message size, it will give you complete messages.

`0xCD` is a standard fill, I think it is for heap, but not sure.

So far, we are reading 64k of data, and writing 2k of data.  It looks like CallNamedPipe doesn't return until the data is accepted (as there is a  timeout  - set to 1000ms).  The behavior of these systems, is that once kernel has the data buffer then the client code is not allowed to change the memory.

I would say the most likely case, is that the buffer is not being filled correctly, and that the amount of data in the server is consistent with messages in the pipe.

You have not provided enough data to verify this.

Comment: I will create a working sample. I wonder how much code I can post. I will create two programs, like in the product. I posted just pseudocode, all the allocations are checked and no failures recorded anywhere, no ERROR_MORE_DATA or any other issues. I log the bytes sent and received - they match only on first block of 2K bytes. The # of received bytes is same as # of sent bytes. Buffer filled with memcpy() from a larger buffer.